# Powershell compare variable1 with variable2

Tags: powershell

I am trying the following:

```
Variable1 = 'jack' , 'brody' , 'zack'
Variable2 = 'zack'
```

every value inside both variable1 and variable2 has the following attributes.

```
jack.username
jack.mail
jack.ou
```

I want compare variable1 with variable2 and only return users that are not present in variable2 and save the result to a new variable3.

"Example jack and brody would be returned to variable3, but not zack as he is present in both variable 1 and 2."

After return I also want username, mail and ou to be available in variable3.

I tried with the following:

```
$variable3 = $Variable1.SamAccountName | Where {$variable2.SamAccountName - 
NotContains $_}
$variable3 = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $variable1 -DifferenceObject
$variable2 -ExcludeDifferent
```

(second one does not return anything if excludedifferent is used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
$variable3 = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $variable1 -DifferenceObject $variable2 -Property SamAccountName -PassThru
```

When using [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7), the `-Property` parameter allows you to specify which property value you want to compare rather than comparing entire objects.

The `-PassThru` switch returns all of the objects in their original form, which would include all of the properties you want.

Although not used here, the `-ExcludeDifferent` switch will return nothing if not used with `-IncludeEqual` because ***by default, `Compare-Object` returns differences***.

---

Alternatively, you can use a combination of [comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7)<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7)</sup> and `Where-Object`. Since `-contains` and `-in` operator variants can support collections and single object comparisons, I would personally use those in favor of singular comparison operators like `-eq` or `-like` to ensure a more robust solution.

```
$variable3 = $variable1 | Where {$_.SamAccountName -notin $variable2.SamAccountName}
```

The object on the left side of the pipe `|` contains the properties that will return after the `Where-Object` is processed. So if you use `$variable1.SamAccountName | Where`, you will only return `SamAccountName` values.

---

<sup>[[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7)]: Note that operators `-notin` and `-in` were added in PowerShell v3. If you are running PowerShell v2, they will not be available.</sup>

Comment: It's unfortunate that `-IncludeEqual` isn't _implied_ when you use `-ExcludeDifferent` - let's try to change that: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11847).

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the `Where-Object` approach is generally slower: it is O(N^2) for collections of the same length; unfortunately, that seems to be true for `Compare-Object` as well, as the relative performance doesn't vary with element count. Both perform poorly with counts starting at multiple thousand elements. With same-size collections with only a few differences, I see `Where-Object` taking 3.5 to 4 times as long, though that is cut in half if you only need which A elements are not in B, and not also the inverse, which `Compare-Object` invariably determines too.